# Python currency styling issue in html

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to add the rupee styling attached with the values using babel [Rupee sign with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAP5o.png)
am using babel to style the currency but after converting the dataframe to html 
am not getting the rupee styled font but some garbage like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH5rw.png) any solution to this ?

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency
lambda x: format_currency(x, 'INR', locale='en_IN')
```

Comment: how about `lambda x: format_currency(x, 'INR', locale='en_IN').replace(u'\xa0', u' ')` and then `to_html`

Comment: Thanks for the ans but still the issue is not resolved am still getting output like "â‚¹ 2,82,015.00"

Comment: The answer that I provided takes a string (450,000) runs it through format_currency and adds the output to a DataFrame and coverts it to_html.  The html table shows the correct symbol for INR.

Comment: So, I assume that you have another problem that in your pandas code, which you haven't shared that is causing you the formatting issue. Please share some additional code

Comment: no there is other issue, actually there is no locale for 'en_IN' installed on my system which was causing the issue. resolved it thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to your DataFrame code, so I can only provide an answer based on your current question.

**PLEASE NOTE:** This is my first real attempt in using Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from babel.numbers import format_currency

indian_rupee = lambda x: format_currency(x, 'INR', locale='en_IN')

print (indian_rupee(450000))
# output
₹ 4,50,000.00

number_of_rupees = indian_rupee(450000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'rupees':[number_of_rupees]})
raw_html = df.to_html()

print (raw_html)
# output
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
     <th></th>
     <th>rupees</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>0</th>
     <td>₹ 4,50,000.00</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

[image: HTML DataFrame Output]

Here is another example:

```
import pandas as pd
from babel.numbers import format_currency

indian_rupee = lambda x: format_currency(x, 'INR', locale='en_IN')

convert_to_rupees = ['12000', '450000', '2000']

rupee_amounts = []

for item in convert_to_rupees:
  number_of_rupees = indian_rupee(item)
  rupee_amounts.append(number_of_rupees)

se = pd.Series(rupee_amounts)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['rupees'] = se.values
raw_html = df.to_html()

print (raw_html)
# output 
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
 <thead>
   <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th></th>
     <th>rupees</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <th>0</th>
  <td>₹ 12,000.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>1</th>
     <td>₹ 4,50,000.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>₹ 2,000.00</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Whoever provided the -1 could you please provide details on why, so that I can improve my answer?